# Hiding divs in a given section based on empty child form input values

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a containing div structure like this:

```
<form id="baseform">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="subheader"><h2>Section 1</h2></div>
     <div class="row">
        <textarea id=T_01></textarea>  
        <input id="T_02" type="text" />
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        [more form fields]
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="subheader"><h2>Section 2</h2></div>        
       <div class="row">[more form field, etc.]
     </div>
   </form>
```

I want to hide those with empty form inputs `.row` divs beneath the `.subheader` on `document ready` (I already am using `toggle()` to show `.row` divs beneath the `.subheader` on `click`).

It seems like something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.row :input[@value=""]').parent('.subheader').nextAll('.row').hide();
});
```

But no dice. Ideas?

Comment: That should be `[value=...]` rather than `[@value=...]`

Answer (score 0):

This would work for most form inputs, however, you may need other conditional logic for checkboxes and radios, which have a value set.  Would need to see if they are `:checked`.

```
$('.subheader .row :input').each( function() {
   if ( !$(this).val().length )
      $(this).parent('.row').hide();
});
```

**edit**  - missed the `:input` in my selector.

**edit 2** - wasn't hiding the actual row, only the form field.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your length check is off. Did you meant 'if ($(this).val().length == 0)'

Comment: nah, the if statement looks fine.  0 equates to false, that's saying, 'if this is false'.

Comment: Ah cool, I'm never trustworthy of if statements in JavaScript/JQuery hehe :)

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in a solution that would work for all types of form inputs and even this isn't working on rows that only have text fields.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ - the `:input` should grab all form fields.  depending on what form fields are on your page, you could simplify that selector by just using `$(':input')`.  A lot of times its easier to figure out selector issues by just trying the selector statement in the console and seeing what it returns.  Use firebug or your developer tool of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".row :input[value='']").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, mattytommo, but this doesn't seem to hide the parent row that contains the form elements, just the form elements themselves. But it is closer! Any idea of what a solution would be that would work for all types of form inputs?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row input').filter(function() {
    return this.value.length ? this : null;
}).parent().hide();​
```

Comment: Interesting. I can't get it to work, but I do have a lot of checkboxes and radio buttons as well (but also some .row with only text fields). Is there a solution that would work for all types of form inputs?

Comment: Three weeks later he finds it interesting ? You can filter anything, but a checkbox is'nt really empty, it's just not checked, same goes for other kinds of input elements, each has it's own property to check, so you would have to check that property for each type, have a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/FYQyw/1/) for å better explaination.

Comment: This is great, but I'm trying to hide the container .row, not the inputs themselves and I also need it to work on document.ready. I deserve the "interesting" remark--I've just been really busy and not always in a good way! Thanks for your help.